# is there any way to put notes on pdf in evince?

Tags: pdf, evince

I am looking for any way to put some comments on the pdf which I open that by the the evince . Is there any way to that?

Comment: you can't edit a pdf file through evice.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I just did.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:**

On newer versions of *Evince* (a.k.a *Document Viewer*) you can edit annotations by pressing the pencil button on top left of the app window (tested on Evince 3.30.2).

**ORIGINAL:**

On the left sidebar, where *Thumbnails* is usually shown, click on *Thumbnails* and select *Annotations*. Then, go to *Add* under *Annotations* there is small edit button. Click on that one and you can add comments on your pdf.

Alternatively, you can use Okular which may offer more options.

Comment: My evince does not have this option to add. I use version 3.18.2.

Comment: You probably need to use a newer version of Evince.

Comment: I discovered that my version has a button on the tool bar to enable the adding notes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although not exactly an answer to your question, if you find using Evince for annotating pdf files cumbersome or if you don't want to install the KDE base for using Okular, you can use Qpdfview. There you can just press Ctrl+A to add an annotation.